# zfit straight line fitting for 2 dim dataset

Tags: zfit

I would like to fit 2-dim plot by straight line (a*x+b) using zfit like the following figure.[image: 2_dim_plot example]

That is very easy work by a probfit package, but it has been deprecated by scikit-hep. https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/scikit-hep/probfit/blob/master/tutorial/tutorial.ipynb

How can I fit such 2dim plots by any function?
I've checked zfit examples, but it seems to be assumed some distribution (histogram) thus zfit requires dataset like 1d array and I couldn't reach how to pass 2d data to zfit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way in zfit currently to implement this out-of-the-box (with one line), since a corresponding loss is simply not added.

However, the `SimpleLoss` (zfit.loss.SimpleLoss) [allows you to construct](https://zfit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_api/loss/zfit.loss.SimpleLoss.html#zfit.loss.SimpleLoss) any loss that you can think of (have a look at the example as well in the docstring). In your case, this would look along this:

```py
x = your_data
y = your_targets  # y-value
obs = zfit.Space('x', (lower, upper))

param1 = zfit.Parameter(...)
param2 = zfit.Parameter(...)
...
model = Func(...)  # a function is the way to go here
data = zfit.Data.from_numpy(array=x, obs=obs)

def mse():
    prediction = model.func(data)
    value = tf.reduce_mean((prediction - y) ** 2)  # or whatever you want to have
    return value

loss = zfit.loss.SimpleLoss(mse, [param1, param2])
# etc.
```

On another note, it would be a good idea to add such a loss. If you're interested to contribute I recommend to get in contact with the authors and they will gladly help you and guide you to it.

**UPDATE**

The loss function itself consists presumably of three to four things: x, y, a model and maybe an uncertainty on y. The chi2 loss looks like this:

```
def chi2():
    y_pred = model.func(x)
    return tf.reduce_sum(((y_pred - y) / y_error) ** 2)
    
loss = zfit.loss.SimpleLoss(chi2, model.get_params())
```

That's all, 4 lines of code. x is a `zfit.Data` object, model is in this case a `Func`.

Does that work?
That's all.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. However, the solution seems to be slightly complicated. Do you know better fit package on python? I just want a package like the cern's ROOT. (probfit is very good for me, but it has been marked as deprecated by scikit-hep)

Comment: I am not sure I follow: for clarification, do you need to do an extended likelihood fit or to fit a function x-y? If the latter, what exactly is the cost function you intend to use? E.g. Mean Squared Error?

Comment: I think that user should be able to choose a cost function what they want. That is a role of fitting package. I assumed likelihood fitting. I just tried to start just simple x-y fitting by linear function with chi-square cost function, but I would like to know how can I extend these features for general (more complex) fittings. My first question explicitly meaned, the zfit supports for these fitting or not.

Comment: I think we fully agree. In zfit, you can use not just _some_ but _any_ loss function. I tried to demonstrate a "sketched" way of how to do an arbitrary but asked more specifically for which one that you need in order to show directly how to do it. While some loss functions can be used with one line of code, others need 3-4 (as above). But importantly: yes, you can do the thing you want. Btw, the above example is not just the implementation of a loss function, but the _whole_ fit

Comment: Edited the answer to include exactly the chi2. Let me know if it won't work or you have any further question